# Constructor on type xxx not found

Tags: c#, winforms

```
class ItemBaseModel : TextBox
{
    public string item_name { get; set; }

    public ItemBaseModel(string item_name)
    {           
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.ReadOnly = true;
        this.Multiline = true;
        this.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }
}
```

So this is my base class, which derives from TextBox control.

```
class ItemWeaponModel : ItemBaseModel
{
    int min_dmg { get; set; }
    int max_dmg { get; set; }
}

public ItemWeaponModel(string item_name, int min_dmg, int max_dmg) : base(item_name)
    {
        this.min_dmg = min_dmg;
        this.max_dmg = max_dmg;
    }
```

And this is my class, which derives from the first class.

Now, the problem is that when I open my ItemWeaponModel.cs file in my solution explorer, I am getting the following error:

[Constructor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah9wZ.png)

Althought I can run my project without any issues. What is happening?
Thanks for response.

Comment: Why are you deriving from TextBox?

Comment: Where are your parameterless constructors? Also, is it a typo that ItemWeaponModel's constructor is outside the class? Please also note that public things in C# AreNamedLikeThis not_named_like_this

Comment: Hey. I've decided that all my items in the game will be in form of text box, so I thought that creating a class, which will derive from TextBox might be a good idea.

Comment: Are your items textboxes? The question to ask yourself when inheriting is "is an X a kind of Y?" - Is a Triangle a Shape? Yes. Is an Elephant an Animal? Yes. Is a Gun a CookingUtensil? Probably not..

Comment: Deriving from `TextBox` can make sense if the text boxes are used as game objects. It is a winforms game after all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the designer expects that your class has a parameterless constructor. It cannot call any other.

Try to provide a simple parameterless constructor just for the designer. You don't have to use it in your actual application code.

```
class ItemBaseModel : TextBox
{
    public string item_name { get; set; }

    public ItemBaseModel(string item_name)
    {           
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.ReadOnly = true;
        this.Multiline = true;
        this.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }
    public ItemBaseModel() : this("default")
    {}
}
```

Comment: better: `public ItemBaseModel() : this("default") {}`, i.e. let one constructor call the other to avoid duplication of code.